# SQL Server hierarchy, selecting parent nodes for distinct IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical

Stuck on this hierarchy problem, so here goes.
I have the following hierarchy table, which has been truncated.

[image: HierarchyIDs]

The hierarchy has been joined to another table on the 'codes' column, with the following sample result. Let's call this table1.

[image: table with hierarcjy]

For each distinct ID in table1, I want to utilize the hierarchy to find a parent, if it exists.
For example, under the codes column, 18 is the parent of 19.
I would like to fold or group the 19 with 18 and eliminate that row.
The desired result is something like this.

[image: desired result]

This does sort of what I want, using the GetAncestor method:

```
SELECT A.OrgNode, A.Codes, A.ID, B.OrgNode, B.Codes, B.ID FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table1 B ON A.OrgNode.GetAncestor(1) = B.OrgNode WHERE A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: I think you had better post some expected results as I cant understand your description

Comment: I can't figure out how get to these desired results from this sample data. Can you explain how you, as a human, get the values in your second row of your desired result? It feels totally arbitrary. You say "I want to apply the HierarchyID" but what does it mean to "Apply" a "HierarchyID" and what is a "HierarchyID" as no such column exists in your data? You then say "with the parent for those codes" Where is a "Parent" in this data, what "Codes"?

Comment: Sorry. Poorly written on my part. Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This self-join, with the GetAncestor function, did what I wanted it to do, with the 'where' on the same ID.

`SELECT A.OrgNode, A.Codes, A.ID, B.OrgNode, B.Codes, B.ID FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table1 B ON A.OrgNode.GetAncestor(1) = B.OrgNode WHERE A.ID = B.ID`